# I am getting bad response from file upload via Dropzone in window7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone js for upload file funxtionality.
In my system it's working fine have configuration window 10,64 bit with firefox 64.0.2 64 bit.
were my collegue have same firefox version but installed window 7.
and its generating bad response.

I am calling ajax method and getting response from server.

Bad response in my collegue pc in FireFox in windows 7:

> GIF89a\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000�\u0000\u0000���\u0000\u0000\u0000!�\u0004\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000,\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0002D\u0001\u0000;

[image]

where in my pc 
success response in FireFox in windows 10.

[image]

My client side code,

```
function dropzonecall(allowcontenttype) {
    Dropzone.options.UploadForm = {
        method:'post',
        acceptedMimeTypes: allowcontenttype,
        clickable: true,
        maxFiles: 1,
        param: { adXmlId: AdXmlId, adType: AdType },

        init: function () {
            this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                displayUploadedFileTab(response);
            });
            this.on("error", function (file, response) {
                alert(response);
            });
            }
        };
     }
```

Server Side code,

```
return Json(new { html = "FileName"  });
```

Comment: The second screenshot looks like Chrome, not Firefox

Comment: yeah, now i have updated with FireFox's image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already faced this issue,

**check your antivirus which will block URL.**

I had installed kaspersky antivirus and thats blocked my url and got bad response,might be same issue will be on your case.